# design a recursive program

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, binary-search-tree

I am not really a newbie in programming, I have been programming for almost three years now. But I still feel frustrated about understanding and designing recursive programs.Sometimes I need to write the whole process down which takes a lot of time. 
Say this program:
Convert Sorted Array to a balanced Binary Search Tree

```
TreeNode* sortedArrayToBST(vector<int>& nums) {
        return help(nums, 0, nums.size()-1);
    }

    TreeNode* help(vector<int> &nums, int start, int end){
        int size=end-start;
        if(size<0)    return NULL;
        if(size==0)    return new TreeNode(nums[start]);
        int mid=(start+end)/2;
        TreeNode* root=new TreeNode(nums[mid]);
        root->left=help(nums, start, mid-1);
        root->right=help(nums, mid+1, end);
        return root;
    }
```

I have a very hard time tracking how the tree forms....And I definitely cannot design a program like this myself. I have seen 30 recursive programs already, I know I need to practice more to get familiar with it. Just want to know how the thinking process is when you design a recursive program and how you understand a recursive program quickly.
Many many thanks!!

Comment: Is your question about how to program recursively or is it anything specific?

Comment: Try to understand the factorial function first. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29

Comment: It's about how to program recursively, I just use the problem as an example

Comment: I can understand easy recursions like  the factorial function. When recursion becomes complicated that's where I fail @Matsmath

Comment: Please **edit** your post and provide some clarity of what you're asking for. Right now all you've provided is a narrative of what you've been doing not what you actually need help with. Just saying _"can you help me with recursion"_ is way too broad and cannot be answered within the scope of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you deal with recursion you need to keep 4 things in mind:

- What are the parameters that define the current state.
- What is/are the ending condition(s).
- What does the call return.
- How do you combine the results from recursive calls to produce an answer for the current call.

In the case you mentioned.

- Parameters are coordinates for a section of a list (start, end).
- Ending conditions: The list section is empty you return null, if the list has one element you return a tree with just that element.
- The returned result: the root fully built balanced tree representing the section of the list from the parameters.
- How to combine results: Pick up the middle point and make it the root of the tree. Set the left child to be the root of the tree for the subsection between the start point and the middle point (recursive call for that list). Set the right child to be the root of the tree for the subsection between the middle point and the end of the list (recursive call for that list).

As long as you are clear about those 4 points most recursive problems become simple. If you want to get better at it you need to practice more problems involving recursion.